# Is it theoretically possible to rewrite tagbody in terms of labels?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I have been thinking about how one could implement common lisp's `tagbody` in a lisp that doesn't provide explicit gotos, but does provide `labels`.

The reason this interests me is that I want to write a recursive interpreter that supports goto statements that work exactly like in common lisp.

Assuming one had `labels` available, would it be possible to implement `tagbody` as a macro written in terms of `labels`?

Consider this example written in terms of `tagbody`:

```
(tagbody
        (go middle)

    start
        (print "start")
        (go end)

    middle
        (print "middle")
        (go start)

    end
        (print "end"))
```

Now consider this other example written in terms of `labels`:

```
(labels
    ((entry-point () (middle))
     (start () (print "start") (end))
     (middle () (print "middle") (start))
     (end () (print "end")))
    (entry-point))
```

On the surface they seem to do the same thing. Does anyone know if they actually do? Are they really 100% semantically equivalent?

If someone wrote a macro that translates one form to the other, would there be edge cases where a subtle difference might resurface? Things such as different outputs for same inputs, or subtle variable scope differences, or differences in stack unwinding, etc.

Comment: See https://gist.github.com/soegaard/3079344 , https://blog.practical-scheme.net/shiro?20110529-tagbody-go-in-scheme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you assume that tail calls are turned into GO TO (which means your code would not be portable CL) then this is theoretically possible, but probably very hard in practice.

The reason it's hard in practice is that you need to handle dynamic state, which would turn into a nightmare.  For instance consider

```
(setf *x* 0)
(tagbody
 start
 (if (> *x* 0)
     (go end)
     (let ((*x* 1))
       (go start)))
 end)
```

where `*x*` is a special variable.  This fails to terminate.  But

```
(setf *x* 0)
(labels ((start ()
          (if (> *x* 0)
              (end)
              (let ((*x* 1))
                (start))))
         (end ()))
  (start))
```

which will terminate under the same assumptions.

There are many other bits of dynamic state in the language, such as catch tags, exception handlers, and just lots of other things which you would need to cope with.

It is easier to think of this going the other way: given a call to a function which looks like a tail call, you need to know about what the dynamic state is to know if it really *is* a tail call.  A `go` essentially forces the 'call' to be a tail call, and thus must be willing to unwind any bits of dynamic state which were established between the `go` and its target.  (I think that in CL you never need to install bits of dynamic state in this case.)

Answer (score 0):

`go` doesn't *return*.  `Go` forms somewhere in the middle between other expressions cannot be trivially translated to function calls.  I think you need first-class continuations for that.

Example:

```lisp
(tagbody
   (something)
 my-first-tag
   (something else)
   (when (some condition)
     (go end))           ; 1
   (fiddle daddle)
   (when (some other condition)
     (go my-first-tag))  ; 2
   (and something else)
 end
   (final thoughts))
```

If in the first pass you jump from `2` to `my-first-tag` and then from `1` to `end`, then `(and something else)` never is executed.  This seems hard to translate into a `labels` form.

Comment: You need to rewrite things so that all the `go`s are in tail position.  In this case I think it's enough to turn `(when ... (go ...)) ...` into `(if ... (go ...) ...)`.

Answer (score 0):

The TXR Lisp [`tagbody` macro](https://www.kylheku.com/cgit/txr/tree/stdlib/tagbody.tl) produces code that wraps a loop around a low-level `switch` construct. The `go` form works by setting the hidden state variable to the integer value corresponding to the desired label, and then abandoning the current form via a dynamic exit. The loop will then switch to the desired target.

The translation of the labels to integer codes, and use of the `sys:switch` special form are implementation details; in principle, one of the `case` macros could be used directly.

The macrology in the implementation doesn't easily transliterate to Common Lisp. It relies on features of the TXR Macro system. The `go` form is defined as a macrolet (as well as a global macro also):

```
(macrolet ((go (:form form label)
             (let ((index (posql label ',lbls)))
               (if index ^(return* ,',tb-id ,index) form))))
  ,basic-code)
```

Note that if `index` is null, it returns `form`. In other words "if the target label is not found in our enclosing `tagbody` we return the unexpanded `form`, thereby declining to expand.

In TXR Lisp, when a `macrolet` declines to expand a form, the macro expander will look higher in the lexical scope for another definition of the macro that has been shadowed, and try the expansion with that one.

This allows `(go label)` that is nested in several layers of `tagbody` to find the innermost one which has a binding for `label`, and work against that one.

If the label is not found, then the macro expander will try the global macro `go` defined by `defmacro`.  That one just raises an error.

How the labels are mapped to integers is simply that the list of labels of each `tagbody` is inserted, as a literal into the `go` `macrolet`. I.e. each level of `go` knows what its labels are: the position of the label in that list is the integer index, and if that is not found, the label either doesn't exist or is in some outer `tagbody`, not this one.
Each `tagbody` instance is identified by a `gensym`, and that is also inserted into the `go` macrolet. That symbols is used to name the `block`s that serve as the exit points for the form abandonment initiated by `go`.

Most of the complexity of `tagbody` is a red herring, dealing with the complexity of setting up the material for `sys:switch` (not a user-documented special form). The compilation strategy for `sys:switch` relies on substructure sharing in the source code to de-duplicate the compiled code, so the macro is careful to bring that about. None of that has anything to do with the semantics of `tagbody` *per se*.

How we can understand it in Common Lisp terms is that something like:

```
(tagbody a (unwind-protect (go b)
             (print 'a-abandoned)) ;; this is executed!
         b (go a))
```

Becomes a loop similar to:

```
(let ((state-0022 'a))
  (loop
    while t
    do
      (block exit-0023
        (case state-0022
          (a (unwind-protect (progn (setf state-0022 'b)
                                    (return-from exit-0023))
               (print 'a-abandoned)))
          (b (setf state-0022 'a)
             (return-from exit-0023))))))
```

In the real implementation we use gensyms for the hidden state and blocks, do something to ensure proper nesting and also have to take care of the termination case: when the `tagbody` executes the last statement which is not a `go`, it has to terminate: for that we can insert a `(loop-finish)`:

```
(tagbody (go b) b (print 42) c)
```

might become:

```
(let ((state-0024 'start-0025))
  (loop
    while t
    do
      (block exit-0026
        (case state-0024
          (start-0025 (setf state-0024 'b)
                      (return-from exit-0026))
          (b (print 42)
             (setf state-0024 'c)
             (return-from exit-0026))
          (c (loop-finish))))))

The salient features are that we translat `go` forms to dynamic exits, as required by the semantics of `tagbody`, to an exit point inside `tagbody`. That exit point selects the labeled statements which execute next, which we achieve by means of a state variable and a `case` inside a `loop`.
```